# Solve python bottle charts

Tags: python, charts, bottle

**I have written this code but I have an error with chart2.Any one can helps? **

```
from bottle import get, post, route, run, template, static_file, request, response, error, redirect, debug, error
from bottle import Bottle

from flask import Flask
from flask import Markup
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@route('/static/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./static/')


@app.route('/')
def chart():
    labels = ["2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4"]
    values = [9,6,6,10,9,7,5,4,10,6,10,8]
    return render_template('chart.html', values=values, labels=labels)



@app.route('/chart2/')
def chart2():
    labels = ["2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4"]
    values = [9,6,6,10,9,7,5,4,10,6,10,8]
    return template('ch.tpl', root='/path/to/file')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True)
```

The error i get is : `"raise TemplateError('Template %s not found.' % repr(name))"`

I get this when i try to call the `/chart2/` view

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Hi @Theodoros, if you can explain what the error you see is, and what you were expecting, then people will be better able to help

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is due to a typo. 
The line `return template('ch.tpl', root='/path/to/file')`

should be `return template('ch.html', root='/path/to/file')`

The error is because there is no view called `ch.tpl`

Comment: I replace 'ch.tpl ' to 'ch.html' and I still have tis error: (File "C:\Python27\student\Average\John's Average\app.py", line 33, in chart2
Open an interactive python shell in this framereturn template('chart2.html', root='/path/to/file')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3605, in template
TEMPLATES[tplid] = adapter(name=tpl, lookup=lookup, **settings))

Comment: Does the file 'chart2.html' exist in your templates folder? is the root of your site an actual file path and not '/path/to/file' as in the code above? and what is the code on line 33 in your editor?

Comment: The file  'chart2.html' does exist in my templates folder. also I change '/path/to/file' to '/file/path' and still the same error.   in my editor the line 33 is the "return template('chart2.html', root='/file/path')"

Comment: @TheodorosIona '/path/to/file' is a placeholder for an actual path to a file. eg "C:\Website\index.html" so changing it to /file/path does nothing to solve your problem.

Comment: I have change my path file "C:\Python27\student\Average\John" and still not work.   (@app.route('/chart2')
def chart2():
   
  labels = ["2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4"]
  values = [9,6,6,10,9,7,5,4,10,6,10,8]
  
  return template('ch.html', root='/Python27/student/Average/John/templates'))

Answer (score 0):

The error is :

```
"raise TemplateError('Template %s not found.' % repr(name))"

@app.route('/chart2/')
def chart2():
    labels = ["2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4"]
    values = [9,6,6,10,9,7,5,4,10,6,10,8]
    return template('ch.tpl', root='/path/to/file')
```

The first is run correctly:

```
@app.route('/')
def chart():
    labels = ["2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4"]
    values = [9,6,6,10,9,7,5,4,10,6,10,8]
    return render_template('chart.html', values=values, labels=labels)
```

sorry about my explanation before.

Comment: You should add this as an edit to your question and not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the template does not define it's root with the `root` keyword.  You have to specify the full path, or add a searchable path to the bottle template path list.  I find it more explicit to just add a the full route.

```
@app.route('/chart2/')
def chart2():
    labels = ["2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4"]
    values = [9,6,6,10,9,7,5,4,10,6,10,8]
    return template('/path/to/ch.tpl', labels=labels, values=values)
```